# Designing a thinner controller in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, sails.js

I am new to MVC programming.Currently I have a `User` model with one attribute `timespent`. I am using d3.js to plot time spent per user in one of my views. The current way I am implementing this is by incorporating all the logic of searching the database and getting the data in the correct format in the `UserController`.

From what I have read on the sails docs, they recommend "thin" controllers whenever possible. Where else can I incorporate all this search/formatting code in a more reusable manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers should be thin because they are controllers :)
It's a very common error when you start using a MVC framework to put the logic in the controller, but definetly it should't be there.

If you are working with data stored in database and related to your model, then I would suggest this logic should be in the model. As many people think, the model shouldn't be as thin as possible :)

And of course if it does not fit there, as Yann suggested, use services. A good part of yout application logic should be there!

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [Sails.js services](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/api/services)

> 'Services' are similar to controller actions but are typically used for things that don't nessecarily have to happen between the time when the user sends a request and when the server sends back a response.